# How can I replace entire column with the same word in a file in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am new to Perl. I want to replace the entire column in a file with the same word. Can any one help me with the code?

Input:

```
PPD5    31-Dec-15   Basel5  No  No      
PPD5    23-Dec-15   Bas_15  No  No      
PPD6    16-Dec-15   Bas3_15 No  No  
NPD5    16-Dec-15   Bas16   No  No  
NPD6    16-Dec-15   Bas18   No  No  
PARU    9-Jan-16    hjfhg15 No  No
```

Output:

```
PPD5    31-Dec-15   test  No  No    
PPD5    23-Dec-15   test  No  No      
PPD6    16-Dec-15   test  No  No   
NPD5    16-Dec-15   test  No  No  
NPD6    16-Dec-15   test  No  No  
PARU    9-Jan-16    test  No  No
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl one liner:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$"="\t"}$F[2]="test";print "@F"' input.txt
```

In script (give script name is test.pl):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$" = "\t";

while (<>)
{
    my @F = split;
    $F[2] = "test";
    print "@F\n";
}
```

Execute as:

```
perl test.pl input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply use Vim for this purpose? It takes you only few steps to do it:

1. Open the file in Vim `vi <file_name>`
2. Go to the first character of the column you want to replace.
3. Press `Ctrl+v`
4. Go to the end of the file by pressing `G` or `Shift+g`
5. Then go to the last character of the column you want to replace
6. Press `c`
7. Type the word you want to replace the whole column with
8. Press `Esc`
9. Save the changes by typing `:wq` then press Enter

[image]

I hope it helps!